# HTML Forms - auto submit to email

Tags: html

I'm making a form for our school website and want it to automatically send the information to an email address.  I'm using html coding and I know it can be done but the coding I'm using opens up my email to send it. I want them to hit submit and it automatically goes to email. Can someone give me the correct code please? The code I found here opens up my email in order to send this. I need to skip this step and have it auto send when I click submit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need a server side language to do that, not just html

Answer (score 1):

You need a server side language such as php to do that, not just html.

In your html form

```
<form class="submit-student-form" action="submit_student_form.php" method="post">
  <h1 class="form-title">Student Detail Form</h1>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Robert Thomas" required>
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email ID" required>
  <label>Contact Number</label>
  <input type='tel' name="telephone" placeholder="+91 91234567890" required>
  <label>Home Location</label>
  <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="New York" required>
  <label>Address</label>
  <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Loreum Ipsum" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Create a php file submit_student_form.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "to@domain.com";
    $email_subject = "Email subject";
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $location = $_POST['location']; // required
    $address = $_POST['address']; // required

    function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Location: ".clean_string($location)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
  <!-- include your own success html here -->

  <div class="feedback">Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I assume, if you say you have made it open up with an email box, that you used the "mailto" command. I always use that for mailing information to a specific email. If I understand, you are trying to send an email without opening that pesky email box, right? Well, I would not recommend that, as how will the computer know where to send the email from? If you want to look into the "mailto" thing, then [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_address.asp) is a great website with examples on how to use it. Good luck with your school website!

Comment: Here is the code I'm using, but when we click submit it opens our email.  Students are filling out this form on our website so we don't need them to open email to send the form.  We just need the info they type in the form.

Comment: <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="mailto:inbox_530@interact.ccsd.net">

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this feature by using Google's Gmail Javascript API.

Please refer:  https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-gmail-javascript-api/

**1. Enabling the Gmail API**:
 Navigate to the Google Developer Console and create a project and generate API key.

**2. Initial Set up:**:

```
git clone git@github.com:sitepoint-editors/gmail-api-javascript-example.git
```

**3. Enter Our Credentials**:
You should enter your credentials in index.html:

```
var clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

Modify the scopes variable definition in the index.html

```
var scopes =
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly '+
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send';
```

**4. Adding the Compose button.**

```
<a href="#compose-modal"
   data-toggle="modal"
   id="compose-button"
   class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Compose</a>
```

The Compose button will simply open a model, which we’re also going to add directly into the DOM.

**compose-modal.html**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="compose-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Compose</h4>
      </div>
      <form onsubmit="return sendEmail();">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="compose-to" placeholder="To" required />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject" required />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-message" placeholder="Message" rows="10" required></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" id="send-button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Send email function:

```
function sendEmail()
{
  $('#send-button').addClass('disabled');

  sendMessage(
    {
      'To': $('#compose-to').val(),
      'Subject': $('#compose-subject').val()
    },
    $('#compose-message').val(),
    composeTidy
  );

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

make a file called done.php and link your sineup form to done.php with POST

add this to done.php

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "email";
    $email_subject = "subject";
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $password = $_POST['password']; 
    function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "password: ".clean_string($password)."\n";
  
// email 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
  <!-- include your own success html here -->

  <div class="feedback">Thanks for submiting we will get back to you as soon as possable</div>
  <?php
}
?>
```